# Assigning data type to multiple objects at same time in r

Tags: r, object, apply, type-conversion, lapply

I'm creating an object with its type as a data.frame, like this

```
df1=as.data.frame(c())
df2=as.data.frame(c())
df3=as.data.frame(c())
.
.
.
df8=as.data.frame(c())
df9=as.data.frame(c())
df10=as.data.frame(c())
```

I want to do this in a single line since every time I 'm explicitly mentioning defining an object and declaring its datatype
So I tried doing this

```
ax=as.list(paste("df",c(1:10),sep = ""))
lapply(ax, as.data.frame)
```

but this gives me an output as list, I tried with apply as well but didn't worked.How do I go for this any suggestions
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply`

```
lapply(vector("list", 10), as.data.frame)
```

Or use a variant

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) as.data.frame(c()))
```

---

Or with `replicate`

```
replicate(10, as.data.frame(c()))
```

If we need some identifiers, then use `setNames`

```
setNames(replicate(10, as.data.frame(c())), paste0("df", 1:10))
```

---

It may not be a good idea to have multiple objects in the global environment, but if the intention is have it anyway (not recommended by us), from the above method, we can wrap it with `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(replicate(10, as.data.frame(c())), paste0("df", 1:10)), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: And this of course produces lists of data frames, which is *much much better* than OP's example of sequentially named objects in the global environment. OP, do it this way unless you really like copy/pasting and find/replace.

Comment: @akrun +1 for listing the global env. point..Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using the assign function too.

```
i = 0
for (i in 1:10){
  assign(paste0("df",i),data.frame())
  }
```

I found this easier, because I can also make a list of all the names that I created and use them for further operations.

Comment: Why would a list of names be more useful than a list of data frames?

Comment: I actually had a class project that was working on real time data, creating data frames based on conditions. Now with real time data, the number of data frames would always vary, but my operations on each data frame were same. Having the names on a list, I could just iterate over the list and use the get function to perform the operations.

Comment: But if you just had the data frames in a list you could use `lapply` or whatever and iterate over the list of data frames without using `get` at all.

Comment: The operations were not small enough for lapply. The data frames were produced based on an optimization code that grouped certain docks of a bike share system. Once the stations were grouped, I had to find the number of bikes to be transferred using LPsolve, and plot them using leaflet. The number of data frames generally varied from 3 to 8, but theoretically, they could have been more than a hundred. I could share my code if you are interested.